# Local mail server for testing (SSL + NTLM) on windows

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, mail-server

I'm working on a java mail client (part of a web application running in tomcat 8)
and the web application needs to be able to send (not recieve) mails.

My web application allows to be configured in a few different ways and I cannot test them all at the moment.

Im using the standard java mail api (https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)

At the moment I do have an exchange account and my application is working with  STARTTLS & Auth. Mechanisms `LOGIN` & `PLAIN` to send mails.

**The thing I cannot test is SSL (instead of STARTTLS) and NTLM as the Auth. Mechanism.** The exchange server is not my own and I cannot have it configured to be working with these settings.

**Does anyone know a way to set up a local mail server so I can test a configuration using SSL & NTLM?**

**Edit:**

I tried hMailServer to test at least the SSL setting but I came across the following problem:

IMAP/SMTP over SSL (using my own SSL cert) is working fine untill I uncheck TLS v1, v1.2 & v1.2 in Settings -> Advanced -> SSL/TLS.

The hMailServer Logfile shows that the connection upon sending mails (using thunderbird with 2 accounts added) is always using TLS.

I would want the connection to run on SSL v3.0 (I know its not the best option but I want to give my application the option to use SSL instead of TLS anyways)

How can I get the connection to be using SSL v3.0?

Answer (score -1):

You can try installing hMailServer in Windows. 

https://www.hmailserver.com 
or you can try setting SMTP in windows8. 
http://www.neatcomponents.com/enable-SMTP-in-Windows-8

Comment: came across hMailServer which would allow testing of SSL but could not find NTLM anywhere in the documentation or configuration of the server. Does hMailServer support NTLM?